# SVG convert issue with imagemagick (pango modules)

Tags: python, image, imagemagick, image-conversion

i'm trying to use the convert command of imagemagick to convert an svg image to png image. When i use the command a i got this error:

```
Pango-WARNING **: No builtin or dynamically
loaded modules were found. Pango will not work correctly.
This probably means there was an error in the creation of: '/etc/pango/pango.modules'
You should create this file by running pango-querymodules.

(process:3665): Pango-WARNING **: pango_shape called with bad font, expect ugly output
(process:3665): Pango-WARNING **: pango_font_get_glyph_extents called with bad font, expect ugly output
(process:3665): Pango-WARNING **: _pango_cairo_font_install called with bad font, expect ugly output
```

This is on a Bluehost hosting account. I use that command in my local machine and i got not error. Somebody have an idea of what could be? I have in mind use this command for my website.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If so, how?

Comment: not exactly. Now i'm using http://phantomjs.org/ to convert my svg files